# Vertical align at center in beamer slides using the [allowframebreaks] option and \newpage

Tags: beamer, floats, page-breaking, line-breaking

I'm writing my thesis slides in beamer. I need to align vertically at center the slide's contents when I use the [allowframebreaks] option in the frame environment and the \newpage to start a new slide.

As the next example:

```
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
                    \frametitle{Outline}
                    Some text....

                    \newpage
                    Some text....
                    \begin{figure}[!ht]
                         \input{myimage.pdf_tex}
                    \end{figure}

                    \newpage
                    Some text....
                    \begin{figure}[!ht]
                         \input{myimage2.pdf_tex}
                    \end{figure}
         \end{frame}
```

Here both figures are always in the top of it's slide, but not in the vertical center. I need to center the content after breaking to a new slide with \newpage.

Thanks in advance. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Remember that there is technically no need to use a floating environment in a presentation. So you don't need to wrap things inside a figure environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `beamer` manual:

> By default, all material for a slide is vertically centered. You can change this using the following class options:
>
> `\documentclass[t]{beamer}`
>
> Place text of slides at the (vertical) top of the slides. This corresponds to a vertical “flush.” You can override this for individual frames using the c or b option.
>
> `\documentclass[c]{beamer}`
>
> Place text of slides at the (vertical) center of the slides. This is the default. You can override this for individual frames using the t or b option.

So you can use something like next code to vertically center your "broken" frames:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer} %<- 'c' is default option, 't' forces top aligned
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[c,allowframebreaks]{centered frame} %<- 'c' forces to forget default
\lipsum[2]
\framebreak %<- with '\newpage' first frame is top aligned
\lipsum[5]
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{top aligned frame}
\lipsum[2]
\framebreak
\lipsum[5]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You used `\newpage` to break the frame but `beamer` says:

> You can insert \break, \nobreak, and \penalty commands to control where breaks
>   should occur. The commands \pagebreak and \nopagebreak also work,
>   including their options. [...] 
>   The command \framebreak is a shorthand for
>   \pagebreak and \noframebreak is a shorthand for
>   \nopagebreak.

If you uses `\newpage` first slide is top aligned, so use `\break` or `\framebreak`.

Just a last comment from `beamer` manual talking about `allowframebreaks` option:

> The use of this option is evil. In a
>   (good) presentation you prepare each slide carefully and think twice
>   before putting something on a certain slide rather than on some
>   different slide. Using the `allowframebreaks` option invites the
>   creation of horrible, endless presentations that resemble more a
>   “paper projected on the wall” than a presentation. Nevertheless, the
>   option does have its uses. Most noticeably, it can be convenient for
>   automatically splitting bibliographies or long equations.

Comment: Thanks @Ignasi now I can make my slides. I really appreciate your help.